# I cannot download the Ubuntu Touch SDK due to Hashsum mismatch

Tags: repository

When I download the Ubuntu Touch SDK, I receive the following erros:

```
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-amd64_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
W: Failed to fetch bzip2:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

Can someone tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say just run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

At least at first it would sound like there was an archive update ongoing at the server, which is a small time period where such could happen.

Comment: Those errors still appear :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove partial files then try to update your list again:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
sudo apt-get update
```

Of course, if you have an unreliable connection it will fail again.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-amd64_Packages /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_universe_binary-i386_Packages
```

I would download the files manually with wget and check with gzip just in case the problem is in the mirror and no locally. If you discover that the servers have problems, then switch them for others.

Comment: I removed the files in the partial folder but the problem persists. The connection is stable all the time, there was no interruption. Is there anything else I can do? It was working fine before.

Comment: You can remove the offending files directly, see my update.

Comment: I still cannot download anything. I tried switching the download server and it finally works!